# Delphi XE5 DataSnap Thread

Tags: mysql, multithreading, delphi, firemonkey, datasnap

I am trying to make a Android/Ios app that connects to MySQL through a DataSnap server.
I want to make this as a Thread. It works fine when I don't use a Thread.
In some articles it is mentioned that when using COM objects in a Thread it is importen to use CoInitialize and CoUninitialize. (But I don't get this to work)

Is this correct for FireMonkey app Android/Ios?

My Thread code:

```
Constructor TDMThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; ServerClassName, ProviderName:String;  var ds:TclientDataset; n1:String=''; p1:String=''; n2:String=''; p2:String=''; n3:String='';p3:String='';n4:String='';p4:String='');
begin
  Inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FreeOnTerminate := False;
  iServerClassName:=ServerClassName;
  iProvName := ProviderName;
  ip1 := p1;
  in1 := n1;
  ip2 := p2;
  in2 := n2;
  ip3 := p3;
  in3 := n3;
  ip4 := p4;
  in4 := n4;
  OutDS := ds;
end;

Destructor TDMThread.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TDMThread.Execute;
var
 par1,par2,par3,par4:Tparam;
begin
  SQLConnection1 := TSQLConnection.Create(Nil);
  SQLConnection1.DriverName := 'DataSnap';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['HostName'] := 'localhost';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['Port'] := '211';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['DSAuthenticationPassword'] := '******';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['DSAuthenticationUser'] := '*******';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['DriverUnit'] := 'Data.DBXDataSnap';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['CommunicationProtocol'] := 'tcp/ip';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['DatasnapContext'] := 'datasnap/';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['DriverAssemblyLoader'] := 'Borland.Data.TDBXClientDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxClientDriver,Version=19.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b';

  DSProviderConnection1:=TDSProviderConnection.Create(NIL);
  DSProviderConnection1.SQLConnection := SQLConnection1;
  DSProviderConnection1.ServerClassName := iServerClassName;

  SQLConnection1.Connected:=True;

  ClientDataSet1 := TClientDataSet.Create(Nil);
  ClientDataSet1.RemoteServer := DSProviderConnection1;
  ClientDataSet1.ProviderName := iProvName;
  ClientDataSet1.Close;
  ClientDataSet1.Open;
  ClientDataset1.FindFirst;
  OutDS.CloneCursor(ClientDataSet1,False,True);

  // Some more code ...
end;
```

Somebody have any thoughts? Examples that works?
I have XE5.1 and working on a Windows 8.1.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: `CoInitialize` is a Windows API call that initializes COM. As Android, iOS, and OSX do not run on Windows and therefore *can't use* Windows COM, `CoInitialize` is not applicable there.

Comment: OK. I removed all code in Excecute except SQLConnection1 := TSQLConnection.Create(Nil); and the app crashes. Can it be the way I call the Thread?

Answer (score 0):

Update information...

It is running now.

I have made this change at the end:

```
procedure TDMThread.Execute;
var
 par1,par2,par3,par4:Tparam;
begin
  SQLConnection1 := TSQLConnection.Create(Nil);
  SQLConnection1.DriverName := 'DataSnap';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['HostName'] := 'localhost';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['Port'] := '211';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['DSAuthenticationPassword'] := '******';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['DSAuthenticationUser'] := '*******';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['DriverUnit'] := 'Data.DBXDataSnap';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['CommunicationProtocol'] := 'tcp/ip';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['DatasnapContext'] := 'datasnap/';
  SQLConnection1.Params.Values['DriverAssemblyLoader'] := 'Borland.Data.TDBXClientDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxClientDriver,Version=19.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b';

  DSProviderConnection1:=TDSProviderConnection.Create(NIL);
  DSProviderConnection1.SQLConnection := SQLConnection1;
  DSProviderConnection1.ServerClassName := iServerClassName;

  SQLConnection1.Connected:=True;

  ClientDataSet1 := TClientDataSet.Create(Nil);
  ClientDataSet1.RemoteServer := DSProviderConnection1;
  ClientDataSet1.ProviderName := iProvName;
  ClientDataSet1.Close;
  ClientDataSet1.Open;
  ClientDataset1.FindFirst;
  OutDS.CloneCursor(ClientDataSet1,False,True);

  // This is new 
  while not terminated do
  Begin
    Sleep(100);
  end;
  // 
  // Some more code ...
end;
```

I found the solution here: [XE5 Android TBitmap.LoadFromStream fail inside a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364812/xe5-android-tbitmap-loadfromstream-fail-inside-a-thread)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in:

[XE5 Android TBitmap.LoadFromStream fail inside a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364812/xe5-android-tbitmap-loadfromstream-fail-inside-a-thread)

its bug in XE5 - the author's solution (sleep in loop) is not valid form of waiting for the thread...

Answer (score 0):

dont use localhost as hostname. on mobile device it is wrong. you need to use actual IP in your local network of machine where server is running