# Error freeing object inside a thread

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I got this procedure to load image async, the problem is when i free the lBitmap Object, if i free i got AV on top, but i need free it because the allocated memory.
How can i free lBitmap Object?

```
procedure LoadMyImage(AImage: TBitmap; AImageURL: string);
var  
  temp: TBitmap;
  lBitmap: TBitmap;

begin
  lBitmap := nil;

  if FCachedImages.TryGetValue(AImageURL, lBitmap) and   (lBitmap <> nil) then
  begin
    AImage.Assign(lBitmap);
  end
  else
  begin
    AsyncTask.Run(THttpAsyncTaskBitmap.Create(AImageURL),
      procedure (ATask: IAsyncTask)
      begin
        TThread.Queue(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            lBitmap := TBitmap.Create(0,0);
            temp := FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.CreateFromStream((ATask as IHttpResponse).ResponseStream);
            lBitmap.Assign(temp);
            FCachedImages.AddOrSetValue(AImageURL, lBitmap );
            AImage.Assign(temp);
            temp.Free;
            lBitmap.Free; //---> if i free the object i got AV on top
          end);
      end);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The mobile compiler is using the ARC memory model. This means that all objects are reference counted and are automatically disposed of when the ref count is zero.

Comment: Under ARC, calling `Free()` simply nils that variable, removing that reference from the object and decrementing its reference count.  The object is not actually freed until all references have been removed.

Comment: See [Threaded Web Image Loader Class For Delphi XE5 Firemonkey](http://www.fmxexpress.com/threaded-web-image-loader-class-for-delphi-xe5-firemonkey/).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364812/xe5-android-tbitmap-loadfromstream-fail-inside-a-thread

Comment: You save lBitmap in FCachedImages, so FCachedImages is responsible to free it. If you call lBitmap.free directly, then FCachedImages will keep link to deleted object. This bug will be invisible with mobile compiler, but you should fix it anyway to keep code clean and compatible with all platforms.

Comment: I note that you're running the entire task in `TThread.Queue`. What exactly is the point of running the task asynchronously if you're not going to process it on a different thread?

Comment: Also the line `AImage.Assign(temp);` is dodgy. By the time that code executes, you should have exited the `LoadMyImage` routine. So what `AImage` refers to at that point is unclear.

Comment: @CraigYoung, the second parameter in `AsyncTask.Run` is running in the main thread. So the `TThread.Queue` here is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is a bad idea to use the same variable in two different thread contexts, unless you specifically need that. Try creating a local scoped variable inside the `AsyncTask` finish procedure instead of using `lBitmap` and `temp` defined in the outer scope.

Also, are you sure you need both `temp` and `lBitmap` in the async task finish handler? I'd say, you should be good with `temp` alone, and make sure to define it locally.